# Downloaded a phising application, what steps should I take next?

Tags: malware

My dad accidentally downloaded a fishy DHL tracking application. The application was downloaded through a SMS he received.

I immediately noticed that the application wasn't accessible through the `apps` list. Whenever I click on it, the apps list immediately closes. The application had access rights to his contacts, phone and SMS. Trying to deny to rights was not possible as the application immediately turned those rights back on.

My first intuition was that `"Hey, an installed application shouldn't have system level access to system applications"` as such, I figured that if kept trying to click the delete button faster than that the application closes the apps list, I should be safe...

And guess what, it worked! I was able to delete the application that way... `lame`.
But now that the immediate threat is gone, should I worry about any lingering landmines?

Is there a way to be sure its all safe? Should I check anything specific? I made sure my dad changed his passwords.

Thanks in advance!